# My router is getting port scan attacks

Tags: attacks, ddos, router, ports, scan

My internet suddenly cut out yesterday, i checked the router and it looked like nothing is wrong. I looked at the logs and i see this

2019-08-18 12:50:39 Security    Warning Detect UDP port scan attack, scan packet from 212.2.127.253
2019-08-18 12:43:19 Security    Warning Detect UDP port scan attack, scan packet from 212.2.96.53
2019-08-18 03:59:04 Security    Warning Detect UDP port scan attack, scan packet from 212.2.96.53
2019-08-17 19:08:37 Security    Warning Detect UDP port scan attack, scan packet from 212.2.96.53

When every attack happens my internet cuts out so how do i stop it?

Comment: You probably can't. Contact your ISP; it's their job to ensure you have service.

Comment: Port scans are pretty common and should not knock down your internet connection. Either the scan and the loss of connectivity are unrelated, your router is buggy or there is more than just the port scan.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely contact your ISP about this and let them know as this is something they should block.

Some ISP's renew the IP of the subscriber every time the router/modem resets, I recommend you try this too.

Comment: My internet is really slow now i dont know what to do, i restarted the router and it didnt change ip, the "attacks" are from the same 2 ip's every time

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Have you contacted your ISP?